# PHP: calculate year count from business start year?

Tags: php, date, date-arithmetic

What is the easiest solution to calculate the year count from a starting of a business.

> We build stuff for 23 years.

I want to replace "23" with a dynamic PHP variable. The starting date of the business is 2004.

What is the shortest and most elegant version to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date("Y") - 2004;
```

Or some variant thereof?